# How to change remote desktop audio quality?

Tags: windows, audio, remote-desktop

When listening to some music on my remote computer, the audio quality is low.
I've found this:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32\Terminal Server\RDP
```

There are two interesting keys:

- EnableMP3Codec - with 0x00001
- MaxBandwidth - this is 0x000056b9

Does anybody know anything about these keys? How should they work? What if i set EMP3C to 0? What if i change MaxBandwidth to higher number? Should i change these on my local computer and/or on the remote computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use VLC or some kind of streaming. RDP is simply not made for this purpose. (Any streaming audio solution can work.)

Answer (score 0):

The registry key you found isn't an important one but be careful when you are editing the registry.

"MaxBandwidth - this is 0x000056b9"

MaxBandwidth is what controls the bandwidth, the hex value "0x000056b9" converts to 22201 which is the speed in kbps.

Doubleing this to 44402 should increase the quality greatly, and 44402 in hex is "0x0000ad72".

Go ahead and change it on both computers from:

0x000056b9

to:

0x0000ad72

You may need to restart your comptuer to notice any affect.

Comment: I've tried this but nothing really changed. Music sounds crap. If I seek in the song, the sound totally screws. I have to logoff/logon to repair it.

Comment: Different music player?